# MySQL PHP PDO Fetch all users with a value of Yes in column

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i have the following PDO to get the users data using the session if it is set.

```
$userClass = new USER();

if (!isset($_SESSION['SESSION'])) {
    $userID = isset($_SESSION['SESSION']); //removes session not set error
} else {
    $userID = $_SESSION['SESSION'];
}

$stmt = $userClass->runQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID=:userID");
$stmt->execute(array(":userID"=>$userID));
$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

using the following if the user is logged in i can display any column that the user has.

using `$user['Username']` or check if they are a model or not `$user['Model']` would result in a Yes or No response.

i have a public page where i would like to display all the users with the Model response of Yes, even if the session is not set, as this is a public display of the model page. I'm not sure how to grab that information without the need of a session. i will include a "?" into the code. that represent the part i am not sure what to put in.

```
$userClass = new USER();
$Models = 'Yes'; // ?
$stmt = $userClass->runQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Model=:Model");
$stmt->execute(array(":Model"=>$Models));
$isModel = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I'm not sure if the `$Models` variable should be preset to Yes because if the response is No then it should not display the user else if it is yes display all users with Yes in the Model column ?

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you want to just grab the users username from the database for example depending on the session they are assigned?

Comment: @Isaac I have that information grabbed already if the users session is set. I cannot seem to grab the column Model if the session is not set. Basically i want to (without a session set) display all the users that are models

Comment: Can you post the DB table that models is in?

Comment: @Isaac this is how the users table looks https://pastebin.com/heXnfWcc

Comment: Couldn't you just loop through all of the models if a user is logged in?

Comment: unfortunately no, because i want to display all the models on a page that is public and does not need a login (meaning there is no set session) on the models page.

Comment: best way to show a table structure is , with mysql client : `describe users;` ... or the DDL if you have it.

Comment: @Isaac  Thanks for the replies i have posted my solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how i solved getting user data without having to have a session set. Using PDO.

```
    $getData = $userClass->runQuery('SELECT Username, Model FROM users');
    $getData->execute();
    $result = $getData->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
    $jsonEN = json_encode($result);
    $jsonDE = json_decode($jsonEN, true);

foreach ($jsonDE as $k => $v) {
    if ($v == "No") {
        // Do nothing if No
    } elseif ($v == "Yes") {
        print $k . " " . $v;
    }
}
```

the following prints out the Username plus the value Yes and if it's No it does nothing.

`Username Yes`

Comment: If you don't want `No` rows, then add a WHERE clause.